# ASP.NET C# BoundField format (Remove leading zeros)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How should DataFormatString of BoundField in Gridview look like that values won't have leading zeros?

So far I got this:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="NUMBER" HeaderText="Id. number" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
```

**Expected result:**

000001 -> 1

002101 ->2101

I tried to figure that problem out with [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this page](http://www.dotnetdawgs.com/post/DataFormatString-CSharp-ASPNET.aspx). So far unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use String.Trim function.  The following code is how I accomplished what you are trying to do:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%#Eval(&quot;NUMBER&quot;).ToString().TrimStart('0')%>" ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The tricky part was using the correct combination of quotes and single quotes.  You can use

```
&quot;
```

in place of the quote character around your datafield column that you are displaying.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to format something properly in a boundfield, I always suggest converting it to a templatefield. It's much easier to work with than boundfields. Here is an example of how the templatefield will look like once it's converted.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" Visible="False">
       <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number","{0:n}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="tbNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Number","{0:n}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

within that template field I placed..

> Text='<%# Bind("yourfield","{0:n}") %>'

This should format it into a number and should drop the leading zeros.

EDIT: You might be able to try

> Text='<%# String.Format("{0:n}", Eval("Number") ) %>'

Comment: What is the data type in your database?

Comment: varchar and I cannot change it.

Comment: humm, what's the reasoning you can't change it?

Comment: @Humpy: the datatype question was unnecessary. the 0 prefix ensures that right?

Comment: I would imagine the datatype question would be valid. If the database was set up properly, meaning that "int" was the data type, SQL drops the leading zero's and all you have to do is bind it. In this case, varchar is being used and therefore is considered a possible mixture between letters and numbers. So this is the reason that the string needs to be converted to an int.

Comment: Humpy, your edited format also don't work. If you have any similar idea you can post it, otherwise I'll use upper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifiying A Kimmels answer, no need to place in a server label, no concern of single or double quotes, no concern of underlying datatype, as it casts the object to string, then performs a string.TrimStart, no need for codebehind

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Work Order">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("WorkOrder").ToString().TrimStart("0".ToCharArray()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

0123456 = 123456

0012345 = 12345

if a server label is required, just start and end the text tag with single quotes

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWorkOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkOrder").ToString().TrimStart("0".ToCharArray()) %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Much cleaner this way.

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id. number">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# ConvertToDigit(Eval("Number")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# ConvertToDigit(Eval("Number")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind

```
protected int ConvertToDigit(object oNum)
{
    var i = 0;
    if (oNum != null) int.TryParse(oNum.ToString(), out i);
    return i;
}
```